# How to download tar.Z files from jFrog repository using Maven?

Tags: maven, artifactory, tar

Please help me to get the tar.Z file downloaded using Maven pom.xml.
or is there any other way I can mange to download?

I am not sure what needs to be done.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why do you need to download a `tar.z`? or are we talking about a `tar.gz`?

Comment: I have not tried anything. It is a tar.Z file and I just want to download it using maven project.

Comment: That does not answer why you need to download that ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.